# Swiper slider, how to reduce the width of the scrollbar

Tags: javascript, html, css, slider, swiper.js

JavaScript

```
 const projectsSwiper = new Swiper(".projects__swiper-start", {
       speed: 1000,
    
             slidesPerView: 3,
    
             navigation: {
                nextEl: ".projects__swiper-next",
                prevEl: ".projects__swiper-prev",
             },
       watchOverFlow: true,
       simulateTouch: true,
    
       spaceBetween: 19,
    
       scrollbar: {
          el: ".projects__swiper-scroll",
          draggable: true,
          dragSize: 80,
       },
    });
```

HTML

```
<div class="projects__swiper-start swiper">
    <div class="projects__swiper swiper-wrapper">
        <div class="projects__swiper-slide swiper-slide">
            <div class="projects__swiper-img">
                <img src="images/projects/slide-1.jpg" alt="slide-1" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="projects__swiper-slide swiper-slide">
            <div class="projects__swiper-img">
                <img src="images/projects/slide-2.jpg" alt="slide-2" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="projects__swiper-slide swiper-slide">
            <div class="projects__swiper-img">
                <img src="images/projects/slide-3.jpg" alt="slide-3" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="projects__swiper-slide swiper-slide">
            <div class="projects__swiper-img">
                <img src="images/projects/slide-4.jpg" alt="slide-4" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Now I have scrolled in full width, but I need to reduce it to 300px and place it in the center, as I found the slider to reduce, but with the width of the scroll, there is a problem.

Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution.
You can set max-width and then use transform to position it in the center.

```
.swiper-scrollbar {
  max-width: 300px;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}
```

Example can be seen here (above style is enough, you can disregard JS): https://codepen.io/burakcanince/pen/orVzRP

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Thank you for your question. It seems like you are not familiar with the standards of Stack Overflow regarding questions. Please read following article: [How To: Ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Afterwards adjust your question accordingly by using the [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77068047/edit) option.

Answer (score 0):

`dragSize` - Size of scrollbar draggable element in px.

[image]

No API option to control the width of `swiper-scrollbar` (The wrapper). If you change this by custom CSS you **destroy** the way the scrollbar works.

```
/* will not work as it should */
.swiper-horizontal .swiper-scrollbar{
  width: 50%!important;
}
```

You should open Github Feature Req related to this idea:
https://github.com/nolimits4web/swiper/issues

Comment: Thanks for the tip